# python 2.7: attach signal handler without setting siginterrupt

Tags: python-2.7, signals

I am writing a utility similar to `tail -f` that uses the following code to attach a signal handler:

```
next_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGIO, handler)
signal.siginterrupt(signal.SIGIO, False)
```

The reason for the `siginterrupt()` call is the following undesirable [side-effect of `signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html):

> Note that installing a signal handler with `signal()` will reset the
> restart behaviour to interruptible by implicitly calling
> `siginterrupt()` with a true flag value for the given signal.

My code seems to work fine, but I worry about the theoretical possibility that the side-effect will cause any signal generated between `signal()` and `signal.siginterrupt()` to be of the non-restarting type, thereby breaking some random 3rd-party library that isn't coded to retry system calls.

I know how to solve the problem using a central registry with a shared handler created before signals are generated. However, such an approach becomes a software layer requiring maintenance. How do I fix the problem without adding a central registry?